# running tomcat as coherence node

Tags: caching, war, oracle-coherence

I have a question for someone who is familiar with tomcat and coherence.

I am using tomcat 8 and coherence 12.2.1 now and here I have, maybe not a problem, but interesting case.

I am trying to start web application on tomcat as coherence node. I already know that there is ExtendTcpCacheService and now I am using it to make additional node which can communicate with coherence cluster.

But my question is: Is there a way to make tomcat start node which IS NOT Extend? I mean, I need tomcat to start coherence node but like grizzly rest server (automatically connecting to existing cluster), not like I have it now - it needs all IP addresses and configuration to connect to existing coherence node.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the other nodes in the cluster have the **ExtendTcpCacheService** enabled and you just want to disable only this service when running in tomcat. This is easy to do and you can continue to use one cache config file for all cluster nodes but you will need to make a slight change to your coherence cache configuration file. Go to the `<proxy-scheme>` section pertaining to your **ExtendTcpCacheService** service and change the `<autostart>` tag with a system-property attribute as shown below:

```
<proxy-scheme>
    <scheme-name>some-name</scheme-name>
    <service-name>ExtendTcpCacheService</service-name>
      ....
    <autostart system-property="ExtendTcpCacheService.enabled">true</autostart>
</proxy-scheme>
```

In the JVM start-up parameters for Tomcat you will need to pass `-DExtendTcpCacheService.enabled=false` to turn off starting the service. In the other JVMs you will not need to do anything since this property is on by default.

You can use this feature to modify almost any xml tag in the coherence config using system parameters. More details on this feature is detailed in the [coherence docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHDG/gs_config.htm#COHDG5032)